# how to save the values from Dynamic textbox to database mysql? -- php, jquery

Tags: php, jquery, database

My goal is to have dynamic textbox and save the values placed in them to my database.
I have here JavaScript that allows me to add dynamic textbox

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    var increment=2;

    $("#addButton").click(function(){
        if(increment > 5)
        {
            alert('You can only add 5 Textboxes');
            return false;
        }
        // two methods
        // first memthod...we can write div element
        var maincontent="<label>Textbox #"+increment+" : </label><input type='textbox' name='textbox"+increment+"' id='textbox"+increment+"'/>";
        var fun="<div id='TextBoxDiv"+increment+"'>"+maincontent+"</div>";
        //$("#TextBoxesGroup").append(fun);

        //second method 
        // here jquery through create div element

        var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr('id', 'TextBoxDiv' +increment);
        newTextBoxDiv.after('').html(maincontent);    
        $(newTextBoxDiv).appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");

        increment++;
    });
    $("#removeButton").click(function () {
        if(increment==1){
            alert("No more textbox to remove");
            return false;
        }   
        increment--;

        $("#TextBoxDiv" + increment).remove();
    });

    $("#getButtonValue").click(function () {

        var msg = '';
        for(i=1; i<increment; i++){
            msg += "\n Textbox #" + i + " : " + $('#textbox' +    i).val();
        }
        alert(msg);
    });
});
</script>
```

this is my form

```
<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
    <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
        <label>Textbox #1 : </label><input type='text' id='textbox1' name="txt[]">
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anybody help me with the php side, on how can I save those to the database? I'm new to php.

I tried doing these

```
<?php
$txt = (array) $_POST['txt'];

if($_POST['submit'])
{
    $add = "INSERT INTO `names` (`first`) values ('$txt')";
    mysql_query($add) or die(mysql_error());

    echo "Added!";
?>
```

nothing happens. It does not add any. please help
If anyone can help me and lead me through line upon line, I would very much appreciate. Thank you all!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is a problem in this line

```
var maincontent="<label>Textbox #"+increment+" : </label><input type ='textbox' name='textbox"+increment+"' id='textbox"+increment+"'/>";
```

It should be

```
var maincontent="<label>Textbox #"+increment+" : </label><input type ='textbox' name='txt[]' id='textbox"+increment+"'/>";
```

And server side you can use

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['txt']) && count($_POST['txt']>0))
{
    $txt = "('".implode("'),('", $_POST['txt'])."')";
    $add = "INSERT INTO `names` (`first`) values $txt";
    mysql_query($add) or die(mysql_error());

    echo "Added!";
}
?>
```

> **I hope this will work**

Thanks

Comment: I really appreciate your help SarwarCSE.
can I show u my whole script, I know it's about to be resolved through your help.

    <?php include("header.php");
    $txt = (array) $_POST['txt'];


    if(!empty($_POST['txt']) && count($_POST['txt']>0))
    {
    $txt="('".implode("'),('", $_POST['txt'])."')";
    $add = "INSERT INTO `names` (`first`) values $txt";
    mysql_query($add) or die(mysql_error());

    echo "Added!";?>
 
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=edit_sport.php">
     <?php  }


-- am i doing it right?